# Dell Precision M4600 won't display 1920x1080@60hz

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dell-precision

I recently upgraded from a Dell Latitude E6510 laptop to a Dell Precision M4600 laptop.  I have two monitors connected to it through a port replicator, one through DVI and one through VGA.  I'm having a problem with the VGA monitor.  The old laptop would display 1920x1080@60hz no problem; the new one won't do it at all.  At best, it would run 1920x1080@30hz, but I can't bump it up to 60hz.  If I turn off the "Use EDID" toggle, I can force it to run at 1920x1080@60hz, but the monitor itself then won't display anything ("Input not supported").  If I connect the monitor directly to the VGA port in the back of the computer, I get the same problem.  The best resolution I can comfortably run at is 1680x1050@60hz.  I've tried switching the cables and using the DVI port, and that doesn't work either.  If I swap back to my old laptop, the monitor works fine.  I've also tried with and without a KVM, which doesn't help (not that I really thought it would), and a mac has no problems displaying the full resolution.  Any ideas what could be going wrong?

OS: Windows 7 x64

Monitor: AOC e2243Fwk

Graphics card: AMD FirePro M4000 Mobility Pro Graphics

Driver: 9.003.3-121120a-150831C-Dell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, it was the monitor cable.  Of the four or five cables I have lying around, only one will allow the right resolution with this card.